# Indexing rows of a table by comparing the values between two cells

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing, comparison

[image]

I have a table like the above attachment. Column A and Column B contains some elements in terms of cell array. I want to create the third column (Level) as the resultant column; based on the following logic.

1. The row for which, value of cell A = value of cell B will be labeled1. (In the 3rd row, the value of column A=value of column B= 3, hence labeled 1).
2. Next, the preceding value will be removed from all
   the cells of column A; and the step 1 will be repeated until all the
   rows are labeled. (In the second step, 3 will be removed from all
   the cells, hence both row 1 and row 2 will be labeled as 2;In the
   final step, elements {1,2} will be further removed from the last row
   resulting the level as 3 )

I am using *cell2mat* and *setdiff* functions to compare the values across the cells, but I am not able to frame the above 2 logical steps to run my code successfully. I have just started learning MATLAB, Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what would happen if row 2 of column B were 3 instead of 2? Is that even possible?

Comment: @ Leander, Thanks for your comment. That's not possible. Assume for a while, this is the given data. What would be the logic to develop the algorithm? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the simplest answer I could come up with, using a single while loop and assuming the cells of `A` and `B` contain row vectors:

```
Level = zeros(size(A));
index = cellfun(@isequal, A, B);
while any(index)
  Level(index) = max(Level)+1;      
  A = cellfun(@(c) {setdiff(c, unique([A{index}]))}, A);
  index = cellfun(@isequal, A, B);
end
```

The above code first initializes a matrix of [zeroes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) `Level` the same size as `A` to store the level values. Then it finds a [logical index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) `index` of where there are matching cell contents between `A` and `B` using [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [`isequal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html). It will continue to [loop](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/while.html) as long as there are [any](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) matches indicated by `index`. The corresponding indices in `Level` are set to the current [maximum value](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) in `Level` plus one. All the matching cell contents from `A` are [concatenated](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) and the [unique](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) values found by `unique([A{index}])`. A [set difference](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) operation is then used (along with `cellfun`) to remove the matching values from each cell in `A`, overwriting `A` with the remaining values. A new `index` for matches is then computed and the loop restarts.

Given the following sample data from your question:

```
A = {[1 2 3]; [2 3]; 3; [1 2 3 4]};
B = {[1 2]; 2; 3; 4};
```

The code returns the expected level vector:

```
Level =

     2
     2
     1
     3
```

Comment: Dude, Thanks a Lot. You saved me. I will be grateful to you, if you can do me a favor by explaining the above. I have just started doing MATLAB

Comment: @pradeepkumarTarei: I added an explanation and some links to the documentation for the functions used.

Comment: However the above code doesn't work for large data. Please consider the following.

_A = {[1,5,6,9];[1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10];[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10];[2,3,4,5,8,10];[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10];[4,5,6,8,10];[4,5,7,10];[4,5,8,10];[2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10];[2,3,5,8,10]};_

  _B = {[1,5];[2,4,5,9,10];[3,4,5,9,10];[2,3,4,5,8];[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10];[5,6];[7];[4,5,8,10];[2,3,9];[2,3,5,8,10]};_

The correct answer shall be : **[3,3,3,2,1,2,2,1,2,1]'** by the above logic.
But, it produces **[0,0,0,0,1,0,2,1,0,1]**; Which is wrong.
Any suggestion/help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: @pradeepkumarTarei: Your example makes no sense. From your requirements in the question, any rows that match between `A` and `B` shall be labeled 1, then have the values they contain be removed from all the cells of `A`. This leaves `A` with 5 empty cells, 1 cell with 7, and 4 cells with 9. If you want something different, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: Yes, You are absolutely correct. Please consider the following as the additional restrictions. 1. Any rows that match between A and B shall be labeled 1, then the same values will be removed from both A and B. Any empty Cell that match between A and B, will be labeled as the Same (Prior) Level. (say 2) 2. Any Unmatched Cell values (or the remaining value in column A), will be labeled the next. (say 3) The above 2 condition will produce the desired result (as in the above example). Kindly suggest/help me to modify the code.

Answer (score 1):

Not my best work, i think it is possible to get rid of the inner loop.

```
% your testdata
A = {[1 2 3]
    [2 3]
    3
    [1,2,4]};
B = {[1 2]
    2
    3
    4};


Level = NaN(numel(B),1);
temp = A; % copy of A that we are going to remove elements from
k = 0; % loop couter
while any(isnan(Level)) % do until each element of Level is not NaN
    k = k+1; % increment counter by 1

    % step 1
    idx = find(cellfun(@isequal,temp,B)); % determine which cells are equal
    Level(idx) = k; % set level of equal cells

    % step 2
    for k = 1:numel(idx) % for each cell that is equal
        %remove values in B from A for each equal cell
        temp = cellfun(@setdiff,temp,repmat(B(idx(k)),numel(B),1),'UniformOutput',0);
    end   
end
```

Comment: However the above code doesn't work for large data. Please consider the following. A = {[1,5,6,9];[1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10];[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10];[2,3,4,5,‌​8,10];[1,2,3,4,5,6,8‌​,10];[4,5,6,8,10];[4‌​,5,7,10];[4,5,8,10];‌​[2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10];[‌​2,3,5,8,10]}; B = {[1,5];[2,4,5,9,10];[3,4,5,9,10];[2,3,4,5,8];[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,‌​10];[5,6];[7];[4,5,8‌​,10];[2,3,9];[2,3,5,‌​8,10]}; The correct answer shall be : [3,3,3,2,1,2,2,1,2,1]' by the above logic. But, it produces [0,0,0,0,1,0,2,1,0,1]; Which is wrong. Any suggestion/help will be highly appreciated. Thank You